# Polynomial $x^2-x-1$ exactly divides Polynomial $a_1x^{17}+a_2x^{16}+1$. Calculate $a_1*a_2$

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Polynomial $x^2-x-1$ exactly divides Polynomial $a_1x^{17}+a_2x^{16}+1$. Calculate $a_1*a_2$

My initial thought was to substitute root from the quadratic equation into the bigger polynomial but seems like the entire degree(2) polynomial divides the bigger polynomial not its factors.

Comment: Hint: The two roots of $x^2-x-1$ are $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\psi = -\frac{1}{\varphi}$. Using [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for Fibonacii numbers $F_n = \frac{\varphi^n - \psi^n}{\varphi - \psi}$, you will find both $a_1, a_2$ are Fibonacci numbers....

Comment: $x^n \equiv F_n x + F_{n-1} \bmod (x^2-x-1)$, where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track. If $(x-r)(x-s)$ divides $p(x)$, then $x-r$ and $x-s$ both divide $p(x)$ (furthermore, if $x-r$ and $x-s$ both divide $p(x)$, and $r\neq s$, then $(x-r)(x-s)$ divides $p(x)$). So, if you plug in either root of $x^2-x+1$ to $a_1x^{17}+a_2x^{16}+1$, you'll get $0$. Can you use some special properties of the roots of $x^2-x+1$ to compute $x^{16}$ and $x^{17}$ at each of the roots, and thus get equations the numbers $a_1$ and $a_2$ must satisfy?

Comment: sum of roots and product of roots both equals 1. Thats all the properties I can think of. How can I use them to compute $x^{16}$ or $x^{17}$  I am not sure. :(

Comment: @BobMcCheese Try calculating the roots explicitly, and compute some small powers of them. What do you find?

Answer (score 2):

I am posting the solution I worked out,

$(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ and $(1-\sqrt{5})/2$ are roots of quadratic equation.

Substituting both roots in the deg(17) polynomial we got,

$a_1*3571 +a_2*2207 +1=0$
and
$-a_1*0.00028+a_2*0.00045+1=0$

solving we get
$a_1 = 987$ , $a_2 = -1597$ .
So
$a_1*a_2 = -987*1597=-1576239$